# Structure relational database for minimising retrieval time

Tags: database-design, relational-database, rdbms

I work a lot with reanalysis data such as NASA's MERRA. These data are downloaded in the netCDF format. The dimensions are longitude, latitude and time, and there are various variables such as temperatures, wind speeds etc. There is one file for all pre-selected coordinates and variables per day. The temporal resolution is one observation per hour, i.e. one file contains 24 observations per variable.

A typical workflow would be: Given a fixed location (characterised by longitude and latitude), extract the temperature timeseries for that location from 01/1990 to 12/1995.

Since it is too slow to open 365*6 netCDF files [from 01/1990 to 12/1995], select the coordinates, extract the temperature variable and concatenate, I tried to store all downloaded data in a relational database [MySQL]. My first naive attempt was to store all data in one table and create an index over longitude and latitude. A query would then simply retrieve all observations for a given pair of coordinates and a time range. This was REALLY slow, since there were several million observations in that table and I needed to retrieve about 180,000 per query. So then I decided to create one table for each pair of coordinates containing the complete timeseries. Given the coordinates, it was easy to select the table and query the time range. This was a lot faster, but now there were more than 1300 tables, and altogether it felt like I wasn't using the database the way it was meant to.

My question: What would be a sensible way to structure a relational database to enable fast queries in this scenario? I used MySQL but my question is not specific to that RDBMS. Would no-sql databases be a sensible alternative?

Many thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? different products might have different solutions for large tables. Also, what timeframe are we talking about here? 365*6 means 6 years of data?

Comment: Yes, 365*6 refers to the example of retrieving data from 01/1990 to 12/1995. I used MySQL, but I am absolutely flexible.

Comment: Are the locations of these 6 years of measurements fixed? I mean, do you have the same set of longitude and latitude just repeated on every date?

Comment: I have a fixed location, say of a roof-top PV panel.I want to retrieve the timeseries of temperatures for a range of time, e.g. six years. The location is fixed.

Comment: Well, I would suggest creating a single table with an index on the date and location columns, perhaps partitioned by year.